# group by max date

Tags: sql, time, group-by

I have following table in my SQL Database and need group it by id and Time2, Where Time2 max on Time2

For example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUQtz.png)

Following table would be my goal:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2qeB.png)

Comment: Tag the DBMS you are using, and your effort so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get rid of the lines in your second picture, the ones which are crossed off, you can simply GROUP BY time2.

Or do you wan to get the maximum of time1 when there are two identical time2? Then you can do

```
SELECT MAX(time1), ID, time2
FROM table
GROUP BY ID, time2
```